# SQL - Retrieve Closest Lower Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When a column value does not equal, I would like to retrieve the closest lower pay value.

*For instance*: 10 yearsOfService should equal the value 650.00; 14 yearsOfService would equal the value 840.00 in the below incentive table,

```
ID   Pay     yearsOfService 
1   125.00      0
2   156.00      2
3   188.00      3
4   206.00      4
5   650.00      6
6   840.00      14
7   585.00      22
8   495.00      23
9   385.00      24
10  250.00      25
```

I have tried several different approaches; including:

```
          SELECT TOP 1 (pay) as incentivePay
          FROM incentive
          WHERE yearsOfService = '10'
```

This works but only for yearsOfService that match.

With 10 yearsOfService:

```
RESULTSET = [1  650.00]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (pay) as incentivePay
FROM incentive
WHERE yearsOfService <= '10'
ORDER BY yearsOfService desc
```